# Issues to download pip install playsound

Tags: python

As there is showing pip install in cmd is installed but in vs code terminal after writing pip install playsound is showing error

Please send me answer and as soon as possible because I am at starting position as beginner in python till a week starting by learning from YouTube.

Comment: Hello! I don't really understand your question. You are saying that `pip` does work in Command Prompt, but not in VS Code?

Comment: please let us know error you are getting?

Comment: The Python installation used by VS may be different from the one used in command line. Each installation has its own set of installed libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling Python with the PIP checkmark turned on. Let me know if that helps!